# How to re-assign array keys to turn into an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
array(
    0 => 'John',
    1 => 'Smith',
    3 => '123-456-7890'
    4 => 'john.smith@company.com'
)
```

And I would like to programmatically change the keys so that the array becomes an associative array:

```
array(
    'first' => 'John',
    'last'  => 'Smith',
    'phone' => '123-456-7890'
    'email' => 'john.smith@company.com'
)
```

What is the cleanest/most concise way of doing this?

Comment: yes, this particular array is just one iteration through a loop. It gets replaced each iteration.

Comment: actually, I'm writing a script to import an excel document where the columns could be in any order, but nice guess!

Answer (score 5):

The [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine) function is probably what you were looking for:

```
$keys = array('first', 'last', 'phone', 'email');

$new_arr = array_combine($keys, $arr);
```

Comment: ooh...the problem with this approach (that I just discovered) is that it requires both arrays to have the same number of elements. I don't know how long the values array will be. I only need to assign keys to the first few items of the data array that I know will be there.

Answer (score 4):

[`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) is probably the optimal approach here. If you have an ordered list you can merge it with the original keys again using:

```
$array = array_combine(array("first", "last", "phone", "email"), $list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array keys are constant, such that 0 is always firstname, 1 is last name, etc...

```
$new_keys = array(0 => 'first', 1 => 'last', 3 => 'phone', 4 => 'email');

foreach($new_keys as $oldkey => $newkey) {
   $orig_array[$newkey] = $orig_array[$oldkey];
   unset($orig_aray[$oldkey]);
}
```

If the mapping isn't constant, thne you'd have to build the $new_keys array dynamically each time, or just do the remapping by hand.

Comment: I was going to answer like this, but `array_combine` might be better.

Comment: It'd work, though if the source array has other keys not listed in the new keys list, it could be problematic.